# Automatically running Scheduled Actions

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-cron

Is there a way to automatically run scheduled action (Tools -> scheduled actions).
At the moment it says they are 'Pending'. They work fine if I run them manually but I need it to run as soon as my products change (I'm using webhooks to monitor adding, updating and deleting of my woocommerce products). Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: That screen is not part of WordPress core, so it must be a plugin. In this case, you'd be best off determining which plugin and seeking support from the developer.

Comment: Scheduled Actions is part of Woocommerce, and it's backed by wp-cron I think. So this is probably just an issue with wp-cron not firing.

Comment: It says that 'woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async' takes two arguments. webhook_id and arg which I'm assuming is the id of my product. How to create a wp-cron that works with all product ids?

Comment: Do you have WP_CRON enabled on your site?